# How can i use the fact that $2^{6600} \equiv 1\pmod {6601}$ to prove $6601$ fails Miller's test?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am currently doing revision and i find a problem here. Can anyone help me?

How can i use the fact that $2^{6600} \equiv 1\pmod {6601}$ to prove $6601$ fails Miller's test?

Comment: Which Miller's test do you mean? The proved-to-be-correct Rabin-Miller test or something different?

Comment: Possibly trying to prove that 6601 isn't obscene? :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller_test

Comment: For a minute I thought Obscene Numbers were like [Odious](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OdiousNumber.html),[Wasteful](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WastefulNumber.html), or [Lucky](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LuckyNumber.html) Numbers...

Answer (score 1):

You cannot. You would need to point to the fact that $$a^{(n-1)/2^k}\not\equiv\pm1\pmod{n} \quad\text{although}\quad a^{(n-1)/2^{k-1}}\equiv1\pmod{n}\qquad\text{(here }a=2, n=6601, k=2\text{)}$$
but as stated, you have no disposal over facts about $k>0$. The Miller-Rabin test uses all $k$ that make $2^k$ divide $n-1$ and looks for such misbehavior, as that is possible (and even likely) only for composites.

Edit: "Likely" only for base-$a$ pseudoprimes, all other composites fail to yield $1\pmod{n}$ anyway.